# Magento2.3.2: All options are not showing in admin panel

Tags: admin-panel, magento2.3.2

When I tried to open the admin panel, admin is opening successfully.

But when I tried to open stores > configuration, all the options are not coming. When I reload, again and again, it's showing properly.

Please check the following :
[image]

Comment: Once run php bin/magento c:f and then check it.

Comment: @Soundararajanm, what this command about please ?

Comment: `c:f` is a short hand of `cache:flush`, it will flush (refresh) your cache

Comment: @RendyEkoPrastiyo, I already run reindex and cache flush lot of times